# Python multiprocessing child process print in Anaconda prompt but not in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, multiprocessing

System: Windows 10 64 bits and Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.9.12.

I have a .py file with the following codes:

```
from time import sleep

def task():
    print('Hello from child process')
    sleep(1)
```

and an .ipynb:

```
from tasks import task
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello from main process')
    process = mp.Process(target=task)
    process.start()
    process.join()
    print('Hello again from main process')
```

While jupyter notebook printed the following 2 lines,

```
Hello from main process
Hello again from main process
```

Anaconda prompt (the black screen) return

```
Hello from child process
```

Is it possible to move the 'Hello from child process' line to the jupyter notebook?

That is

```
Hello from main process
Hello from child process
Hello again from main process
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround solution is to write the print message into a txt file, and read it in the main file.

Print function or even error message of child process only appears in terminal.

.py file

```
from time import sleep

def task():
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Hello from child process')
    sleep(1)
```

an .ipynb:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from tasks import task

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello from main process')
    process = mp.Process(target=task)
    process.start()
    process.join()
    
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
    
    print('Hello again from main process')
```